# MOVE A CI file.yml TO GITHUB ACTIONS

Tags: ubuntu, yaml, github-actions, gitlab-ci.yml

Hello everyone I am having an issue with moving from a yml extension file to GitHub actions and will like a little aid from you. here is a pic on how my yml file looks like and what can be its equivalent using GitHub actions?

### if pic not visible the yml code looks so;

platform:
os: linux
arch: amd64

steps:

- name: 5.0.0+stable
  image: ocaml/opam:ubuntu-20.04-ocaml-4.12
  commands:

  - sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -y install wget pkg-config libgmp-dev m4 libdw-dev jq python3-pip autoconf jo
  - pip3 install intervaltree
  - sudo chown -R opam .
  - eval $(opam env)
  - opam update
  - opam install dune.2.9.0
  - eval $(opam env)
  - export ITER=1
  - export OPAM_DISABLE_SANDBOXING=true
  - TAG='"run_in_ci"' make run_config_filtered.json
  - USE_SYS_DUNE_HACK=1 RUN_CONFIG_JSON=run_config_filtered.json make ocaml-versions/5.0.0+stable.bench
  - ls _results
  - cat _results/*
    -------------------------------------------------------------------[file.yml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/reXmA.png)
    Have started browsing Some GitHubs docs but haven't come accross any helpful tip yet

Here is what I tried and the results I got[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wgUa.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FDM5K.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO @Abdou Rahim. When asking a question, please specify what you have tried an how it did not work. Just pasting some code and asking someone else do the work, is usually not a good way to get an answer.

Comment: hello, thanks very much for your guidance, I have updated the question and have made sure to include what I tried and the results I got

Comment: Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask a good question

Comment: Thanks for this pointer. I will take a look at it